# nearest neighbors degrees of freedom

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour, polynomial

For polynomial fitting with a polynomial of degree $n$, we have $n$ degrees of freedom. Is there a similar concept for $k$ nearest neighbors? Is there any way to compare the degrees in general? I come from an EE background so I might not familiar with some of the advanced terminology.

Comment: Polynomials of degree $n$ have $n+1$ d.f.

Answer (score 1):

It is roughly $N/k$ where $N$ is the number of data points. See here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)
http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Teaching/CS340-Fall07/L4_knn.pdf